# Moment.js and timezone doesn't work only on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, timezone, momentjs

I added moment.js to manage the timezone in my webapp. I setup my devices in New Zealand (GTM +13) and works fine on:

- Iphone: Safari & Chrome
- Android: Firefox
- OSX: Safari & Chrome

Returns 1 more day (I'm in GTM +0). But it doesn't work on Android Chrome (I tested it with several Android devices) and I don't have any idea why. My code:

```
  var dateFunctions = {

    "getCurrentDate": function(){
      return moment().valueOf();
    },

    //I need Date type to use in a custom Calendar component.
    "getFormatDate": function(dateLong){
      var d = moment(parseInt(dateLong)).toDate();
        },

   //For jquery calendar. input: Date without local time; output: timestamp
   "getDate": function(date){
      var currentDay = moment();
      var d = moment(date).set("hour",currentDay.get("hour")).set("minute",currentDay.get("minute")).set("second",currentDay.get("second")).set("millisecond",currentDay.get("millisecond"));
      return d.valueOf();

    },

        ...
        }
```

...
...

```
//it should return tomorrow (GTM +13) in Android Chrome
var currentDay = managedates.getFormatDate(managedates.getCurrentDate())
```

I think that maybe it's related with the google account associated with the Android device. Any idea?

Edit: I edited it to add my updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Your `timezoneOffset` variable name is actually a time zone identifier, not an offset.  Not a big deal, but could cause some confusion.
- You actually don't need moment-timezone here at all.  Moment.js can work in the local time zone without help from moment-timezone.
- Time zones are irrelavent when you're working with numeric timestamps anyway.  Unix time is always UTC-based.
- No need to be using seconds-based functions with */ 1000.  Moment can handle that for you.

Your code, corrected:

```
"getCurrentDate": function(){
  return moment().valueOf();
},

"getFormatDate": function(dateLong){
  return moment(dateLong).toDate();
},
```

One step further - since you are only working with numeric timestamps and date objects, there's really no good reason to use Moment here at all.

```
"getCurrentDate": function(){
  return Date.now();
},

"getFormatDate": function(dateLong){
  return new Date(dateLong);
},
```

If you were trying to work with local time, you'll need to be clearer about how you're sending data back and forth.  You can't do that with timestamps and retain the local time.  There is no information about local time or time zone in a Unix timestamp.

Comment: The webapp is about bookings and the server cannot check the timezone of the client so the client have to send the correct dates (if the client is from New Zealand GTM +13, he needs to send the next day to the server). The webapp works with timestamps (it only needs to check the day and not the time) so I need to add the timezone when I convert the date to another format for display it or send it to the server. I try with your code and you're right, I don't need moment-timezone, thanks. But the problem with Android Chrome (only in this case) doesn't have disappeared.

Comment: Consider using moment's `format` function, so you can send back a string.  ISO8601 is usually the way to go.